# Register for UINavigationController Delegate

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using Storyboards and I basically have this:
[image]

It's a mapView that presents modally a UINavigationController with a UIViewController subclass as its contentViewController (Location).  Then that LocationViewController pushes another viewController based on the table selection (EditLocation).

In EditLocation, I want to pass back information when popViewController is called.  I thought that I could use the UINavigationControllerDelegate to do that.  So in Location, I try:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowEditLocation"]) {
        UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;


        if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
            [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
        }
    }
}
```

This Location class conforms to the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol.  However I never get the willShowViewController or didShowViewController callbacks from the UINavigationController protocol.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prepareForSegue method is invoked whenever a segue is about to take place.I tried accessing navigationController in viewDidLoad of MapViewController(means the viewController which loads when any cell in tableview is selected) and i got the proper description for that as follows.

```
NSLog(@"desc: %@", [[self navigationController] description]);

2012-06-01 12:01:09.986 Sample_Storyboard[1126:207] desc:<UINavigationController: 0x68378e0>
```